# Question about enums in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to use an enum in a for loop like this:

```
enum foo
{
    foo_0, 
    foo_1,
    foo_2,
    foo_3,
    ...
    foo_n,
    foo_count
};

for(foo f = foo_0; f < foo_count; ++f)
```

and I had a compilation error. I understand that this is not valid because ++f might not be a valid foo enum - not in this case but in general case so I switched the for loop to this:

```
for(foo f = foo_0; f < foo_count; f = foo(f+1))
```

which compiles fine. But this rises the fallowing question. What happens if I have the fallowing statement?

```
foo f = foo(k); //k is not a valid foo value
```

Is this undefined behavior?

EDIT: k is an int and it hasn't any corresponding value in foo

EDIT2:

```
enum foo
{
    foo_0, 
    foo_1,
    foo_2,
    foo_3
};

foo f = foo(100); //what value will have f after this according to the standard
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I had a compilation error. I understand that this is not valid because ++f might not be a valid foo enum.

No. That is wrong interpretation of the error. It doesn't compile because there is no `operator++` defined for `foo` type.

If you define `operator++` as:

```
foo & operator++(foo & f) 
{  
   return f = foo(f+1); 
}
```

Then `++f` would compile and work : http://ideone.com/1GG09

And as for `foo(f+1)` (or `foo(k)`), then that is okay. Internally,`foo` is an integral type. And it's value can be anything which can be represented by the underlying integral type.

§7.2/6 says,

> For an enumeration where e<sub>min</sub> is the smallest enumerator and e<sub>max</sub> is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type **in the range b<sub>min</sub> to b<sub>max</sub>**, where b<sub>min</sub> and b<sub>max</sub> are, respectively, the smallest and largest values of the smallest bit-field that can store e<sub>min</sub> and e<sub>max</sub>) **It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators.**

---

EDIT:

```
 foo f = foo(100); //what value will have f after this according to the standard
```

I think the behavior is **unspecified** here, as the Standard says in §7.2/9,

> An expression of arithmetic or enumeration type can be converted to an enumeration type explicitly. The value is unchanged *if it is in the range of enumeration values* of the enumeration type; **otherwise the resulting enumeration value is unspecified.**

For enumeration range, see the previous quotation.

Comment: I want to say that ++ operator can't be defined as default operator for an enum because it's behavior can't be well defined for every enums. My question is what happens when I try to init an enum type with an invalid int value.

Comment: @Felics: Invalid int? I commented on that part also.

Comment: for example I have an enum with internal values 0, 1, 2 and I try to init it with int 3

Comment: @Felics: That is okay, as I said in my answer. The underlying integral type can represent `3` as well.

Comment: @Felics, you'll end up with an enum value that isn't defined in your enum, which is all right by the C++ rules, just probably undesirable for your program. There are no runtime checks for enum values.

Comment: @Felics: I also quoted the reference from the Standard.

Comment: @Nawaz no it's not guaranteed to remain `3` because `3` is outside of its range. The reasoning "the underlying integral type can represent 3" is not sufficient.

Comment: I will remove the "Accept answer" to leave this question open until is clear what will happen for my second edit case

Comment: @Johannes: No. I think `3` is not outside the range. To represent `2` (binary : `10`), you need atleast `2` bits, which can represent `3` also (binary : `11`).

Comment: @Nawaz you are right with that, but wrong with the other thing. I was mislead in head. What I wanted to say is that it works not because the integral type can represent 3 but because it's within the range of the enumeration. if you would take `4`, then it would not be guaranteed remain `4`, even though it's within range of the underlying type.

Comment: @Nawaz Nice one with sizeof(100);)

Answer (score 4):

It's defined behavior. The value that ends up in `f` is unspecified if `k` is outside the range of values of `foo` and is the same as `k` if it is inside of the range of values of `foo`.

The range of `foo` is `0 .. 2^(ld(n+2)+1) - 1`. That is, the values of a bitfield that can store all the values of your enum constants (enumerators).

Answer (score 0):

In that case `f` would have the value k but this doesn't correspond to a label in the `enum`. Think of the `enum` as an `unsigned int` as the data type (unless set otherwise) and the identifiers inside the `enum` as constants.